# How to make text of <p> not move

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have this page:

[image]

When I hover on the item, this happens:

[image]

What I need to happen is, the text should not move to the left when the minus icon appears. How shall I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the code that you are having problems with. We can't help you fix code that we can't see!

Comment: the icon takes part of the width of the white area. Which means the <p>-Element gets smaller, Text is still in the middle. You could work with positions and z-index or you could put the icon in a div and add an empty div to the left of the <p> element that has the same width as the icon div, so the <p> stays centered

Comment: It's not impossible, but it's also not straightforward to help you learn how to fix this, without seeing your markup and your styling. If you could add your HTML and CSS to the question, that would help greatly - thanks.

Comment: @FluffyKitten posting the code here was kinda tricky since my HTML is almost empty because the elements were being created dynamically.. should I have posted the CSS and JS in that case?

Comment: You can post the HTML that is generated dynamically - it doesn't matter what is creating it, it still ends up as HTML, and that is what the CSS is being applied to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you:

```css
.todo-item {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item .remove-icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  right: 0;
}

.todo-item:hover .remove-icon {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <h1>
    TODO App
  </h1>
  <div class="todo-item">
    <p>Sleep</p>
    <span class="remove-icon">(Remove)</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Good Luck...

Answer (score 1):

One very "old fashion" way to solve this issue is by `absolute` position icon.

```css
h1{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 60px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Center</p>
    <img class"icon" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="icon" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text </p>
    <img class"icon" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="icon" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is (likely) because in the first image the P is 100% width, and in the second 90% width the minus being the other 10%. In both cases the text is in the middle. You could add a background color to the P to see the effect better.

There are multiple solutions, but I'd go for making the minus position absolute. That way it has 'no' with because it'll be a layer *over* the P. On the hover, the P still is 100% width.

Alternatively, you could make the P always 90% width, then it wont change either and you would'nt need the position absolute. In order to make the text centered again, you can also make it 80% width, with a margin-left of 10%.

<sub>* the 90% and 10% are example values, it's probably another value</sub>

Comment: Hi, having inspected the <p> after the icon shows up, it is still the same width. The icon is on top of it

Comment: @DhruvErry Please [edit] your question to include any additional information that will help you get the right answers. Without all the information (such as the code!) we can only guess at what is wrong and you are unlikely to get a specific answer that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to add to the left side of the "Sleep" container a padding or margin, with the same width as the icon on the right.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions depending on how your html is build. One way is something like this. If you add a Spacer-Element to the left and put the icon in a div, set all 3 elements to a specified width the p-element will always stay centered no matter if the Icon is shown or not. Hover on the right grey area to show the effect.

```css
.row{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.spacer {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.icon{
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.icon:hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="spacer">
  </div>
  <p class="text">Sleep</p>
  <div class="icon">
    Icon here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary:

Your issues is coming because first of all in `<p> tags` you must have added `text-align:center` and secondly, because your `<p> tag` and  `- icon whatever tag you have used are siblings` and the width of `<p>` changes when it is added.

As it should not disrupt the `<p>` element, you should use `position:absolute` as it would not affect your "normal flow of UI in page".

```css
body {background: #ccccff;padding:20px;}
.container{width:500px;margin:auto;text-align:center;}
div {font-size:30px;}
p {background:blue;text-align:center;margin:0;position:relative;}
.minimise {position:absolute;background: red;top:0px;right:20px;}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div>Things to do.</div>
  <p>Sleep</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>Things to do.</div>
  <p>Sleep <span class="minimise"> - </span></p>
</div>



</body>
```